# React post Build - Classes & Hooks dont Render

Tags: reactjs

I finished working on an app project and I built the final project. The problem is that the classes and hooks get placed but didn't render in the final version for some reasons...
Here you can find the live version https://www.htfgamestudio100.com/
Inspecting it you will find the content div that has the main logic of the app. All the classes and hook functions didn't get render at all but the logic get placed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Style is missing width, height & background-size (cover/contains etc), as your image is in the background the button cant size around it, so you would need to specify the dimensions to 'contain' it correctly.

```
<button alt="Lost Ark WIP" title="WIP" value="" id="MonsterId1" style="background-image:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/XePN4.jpg);height:10px; width:30px;background-size: cover;"></button>
```

see [pen](https://codepen.io/sajrashid/pen/jOGEVKz)

Comment: I use them in the css of each file but instead I'm using the 100% for width and height this way it covers the container. While the container is defined with vh and vw
The problem is the whole section Content get broken after I build it. In localhost it shows perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem... For some reasons my div's opacity is dropped to 1% so they become invisible. I fixed the problem by finding where I use opacity and changed it from 90% to 0.9. Seems that react can't understand the opacity expressed in % for some reasons.